# Are open questions like many Community Wiki questions on StackOverflow allowed?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I was wondering whether a question on the benefits of a TUG membership for students and people's experiences is something that would fit on tex.stackexchange.com. It obviously has no real answer, it's just people's opinions, so Community Wiki seems a good idea but the practice doesn't seem popular here, unlike StackOverflow where open questions such as this one are quite common. And I'm not sure whether a question not directly related to the actual producing of documents is allowed.

So my question is: do topics like the one I suggested have a place on the frontpage?

There are already some Community Wiki questions on the front page, but I believe this one differs from instances like

- [Which packages can you use to improve the typographic quality?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3395/which-packages-can-you-use-to-improve-the-typographic-quality)
- [What are other good resources on-line for information about TeX, LaTeX and friends?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-are-other-good-resources-on-line-for-information-about-tex-latex-and-friend)

Comment: Look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66622/subjective-questions-community-wiki-what-are-the-rules-and-why

Answer (score 3):

(Not really an answer but everyone should see this)

Actually, community wiki questions have now been switched off on all SE/SO sites.  Moderators can still make questions CW but only after they've been asked.

For more, start with: [Community Wiki checkbox missing in action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action) and follow the links.

Comment: Thank you for the info. That should have been announced on the se blog.

Comment: @Caramdir: I think so too.  I found out about it from meta.mathoverflow (ironic since mathoverflow is the one site unaffected by this).

Comment: Big change, nine days old;  I tend to check into meta.so every couple of days, and I didn't see this.